# Getting JQuery to create multiple buttons that are styled in a group with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So fair warning, I'm a novice when it comes to most things-JS.

I'm working on a unique project wherein I am customizing the visual appearance of a sub-section of a website for a product my company owns. I cannot alter the HTML code of the pages (for reasons above my pay-grade), so everything I'm adding/changing is being done through a combination of JS and CSS.

My issue is that I have created a series of buttons which I have organized into a group in CSS. I am placing the buttons on the page using JS, with functions for what each button is supposed to do (generally just navigating to a URL), and then further modifying the location of the button group via CSS. I was able to do this easily enough when the buttons were not grouped using CSS, but then I realized I needed the buttons organized seamlessly next to each other, while using the `margin-left` property to slide the group as a whole to a specific part of the page.

The JS code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="goHome()" class="toolbar-btn">Home</button>');
    }
);

function goHome() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.home-page.org/';
    }     

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="contact()" class="toolbar-btn">Contact Us</button>');
    }
);

function contact() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.home-page.org/contact/';
    }
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.toolbar-btn-group .toolbar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #780a29;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}
.toolbar-btn-group .toolbar-btn:hover {background-color: #490619
}
.toolbar-btn-group {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

The output result is just generic buttons with no styling, and not on the screen where I want them (they're appended correctly, they just aren't sliding to the right due to the lack of CSS stlying). They function correctly, but that's it.

If I've understood my own code correctly, what's happening is that the JS is creating the buttons, assigning them as the `toolbar-btn` class, and appending them to the `#productToolbar` div. They are not receiving the `.toolbar-btn` CSS styling, because they are a child of the `.toolbar-btn-group` class.

What I don't know how to do though, is write JS code that will create the group of buttons with the requisite number of buttons that will receive the CSS styling (assuming it's possible).

Comment: "They are not receiving the .toolbar-btn CSS styling, because they are a child of the .toolbar-btn-group class."  Did you mean to say they are *not* a child of .toolbar-btn-group?

Comment: Whoops, you are correct!

Comment: Excellent -- I hoped that was it.

Comment: @EtherealBug Are you going to edit the question to correct the typo?

Comment: Do you think I should? I just got done editing it actually, fixing some formatting. I thought I'd leave the typo to allow the context of this comment chain to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution, assuming this doesn't mess up other layout in the page, would be to add that `.toolbar-btn-group` class to the container while you're at it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="goHome()" class="toolbar-btn">Home</button>');
  $('#productToolbar').append('<button onclick="contact()" class="toolbar-btn">Contact Us</button>');
  $('#productToolbar').addClass('toolbar-btn-group'); // <-- here
});
```

```css
.toolbar-btn-group .toolbar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #780a29;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.toolbar-btn-group .toolbar-btn:hover {
  background-color: #490619
}

.toolbar-btn-group {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="productToolbar"></div>
```

If that would cause problems -- i.e. if you don't want some or all of the `toolbar-btn-group` styling to affect the product toolbar -- you may need to just duplicate the CSS specifically for the product toolbar element:

```
#productToolbar .toolbar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  /* ...etc... */
}
```

Far from ideal, of course, but so's the whole situation.  (I sympathize. Been there too.)

Comment: Thanks, your first solution was perfect! As it stands ,the `#productToolbar` is actually completely empty on the pages I'm working on, it's a hold-over from the other parts of the website's HTML template. Since everything I'm adding to it will be formatted the same, it doesn't matter if the styling affects the whole div. That said, I'm glad you added that as an alternative as that actually solves a problem I was having elsewhere!